# Multi domain, multi sites with different themes and content

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have about 300 domains I need to setup wordpress. Then for each of them, I need different theme, and content of the sites will be different as well.

I have seen plugins and wordpress as network.

Some of them install the new instance in a subfolder, some in new subdomain.

What I am interested is in domain level. ie:

```
foo.com
bar.com
```

I want to have a single installation and manage `foo.com` and `bar.com` in the same instance for simplicity, authentication and management.

is there a plugin to do this? or an easy way.

I am using Go-daddy VPS that gives me CPanel.

Comment: there are good articles on the web how to do it. Did you try google search before asking here?

Comment: Please read this article for multisites http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WordPress multi-site will handle this easily.  This is what drives WordPress.com and the millions of sites (and domains) hosted there.

Each site in a multi-site can use it's own theme, will host separate content, etc.  Whether you use the subdomain or subfolder install, you will need to use domain mapping to route foo.com and bar.com properly.

The most common plugin I see used for this is MU Domain Mapping:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

There are a few things notably different between WP single and WP multi.  Several good posts on the WP Codex cover the details.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network