# Multisite with 2 different themes

Tags: multisite

I have a site that is under reconstruction - it's going to be a multisite one site for private clients and one for business clients. Now I am pretty okay with the business site but when it comes to the private site it is still not quit what I had in mind. So I found a template that I really like and my Q is:

would it be possible to run one theme for the business site as it is now and then add a now theme for the private site?

the landing page would be www.blabla.com and then

www.blabla.com/business

www.blalba.com/private (here is it that I wish to install the new theme)

Will it work and what do I need to do ?

Thanks for all the help I can get!

Comment: yes you can activate a different theme for each site in a multisite install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi domain, multi sites with different themes and content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206497/multi-domain-multi-sites-with-different-themes-and-content)

Answer (score 9):

KongA,

Yes, you can use multiple themes when using WordPress multisite. In the Network Admin you can install themes and activate them for the network. You can activate Theme A and Theme B both.

Once activated, you would visit Site A's wp-admin and choose Theme A under Appearance.

Then repeat the process for Site B. Under wp-admin > Appearance you'll find Theme B, which you can activate.

Hope this help.